# How to extract system startup logs from guest esp. on boot failure?

Tags: virtualization, boot, kernel, debugging

Given you have a libvirt guest VM which has all possible startup logs verbosely enabled (kernel loglevel, syslogd, dmesg etc. depending on distro).

How to extract these startup logs to the host system esp. in case there is an early kernel error which causes the VM boot process to fail?

Comment: You assume something was written to disk. If the failure was early enough, this might not be true.

Comment: I mean log seen on console